# Invalid cross reference Error: Record Type ID: This ID Value Isn't Valid For The User:

Tags: record-type, exception, workbench, insert, invalid

While inserting data, though I do provide exact RecordTypeID by querying on workbench, I am unable to load only left with below error.

Can someone please help?

```
Record Type ID: This ID Value Isn't Valid For The User:
```

Comment: goto user's profile and check the record Type is available for that user or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to user's profile and check the record Type is available for that user or not.

If not add the recordType for that profile. Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Yes I made it available from Record Type Settings. Still the issue persists.

Answer (score 2):

Profiles have record type settings. This error means that the user has a profile for which that record type is not enabled. You need to make sure the profile you're using has access to the desired record type.

[image]